# Is $‎‎‎\sqrt[3]{y^3}‎‎‎$ or $\frac{x^2}{x}$ a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

A polynomial is a mathematical expression involving a sum of powers in one or more variables multiplied by coefficients.
Now are

$$‎‎‎\sqrt[3]{y^3}‎‎‎,\quad \frac{x^2}{x}\quad\text{or}\quad\left|x\right|\sqrt[2]{x^2}$$

polynomials?

I think $$‎‎‎\sqrt[3]{y^3}‎‎‎\quad\text{and}\quad\left|x\right|\sqrt[2]{x^2}$$ are polynomials (since $x$ may be any number), but $\frac{x^2}{x}$ is not a polynomial (since $x\neq 0$)

Comment: They are polynomial _functions_ (except that the second one has a removeable singularity at $x = 0$), but the expressions are _not_ polynomial.

Comment: @Dr.MV $y\mapsto \sqrt[3]{y^3}$ is a polynomial function, but $\sqrt[3]{y^3}$ is not a polynomial expression.

Comment: If you use the principal branch of the cube root, for example, $((-1)^3)^{1/3} = e^{i \pi/3} \ne -1$.

Comment: The same way $\frac{x^2}{x}$ not a polynomial, because the function $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x^3}$ is not defined on the interval $ (-\infty, 0)  $

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Do $\sqrt[3]{(-1)^3}$ is not  (-1)? Please explain more

Comment: @A.G function $\sqrt[3]{z}$ is multivalued -- at every point $z\ne0$ it takes three distinct values. One of them at $z=-1$ is $-1$, but this is not the *principal* value.

Comment: This is used in working with complex numbers.  If $z = r e^{i\theta}$ is the polar representation of the complex number $z$ with $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$ and $r >0$, the principal branch of $z^\alpha$ is $r^\alpha e^{i\alpha \theta}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, these are not polynomials.

- All polynomials are continuous, $\frac{x^2}{x}$ has a hole at $x=0$.
- All polynomials are single-valued, which fails with $\sqrt[3]{y^3}$ on the complex plane.
- All polynomials are holomorphic. The function $|x|\sqrt{x^2}$ is not.

Comment: @Dr.MV $(1^3)^{1/3}=1^{1/3}\in\{1,\tfrac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2},\tfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\}$

Comment: "All polynomials are continuous, $\frac{x^2}{x}$ has a hole at $x=0$". A hole in the classically assumed domain does not make a function non-continuous.  $1/x=f(x): \mathbb R\ \{0\}\to\mathbb R$ is very well contionous.

Comment: I'd say all of these are polynomials in $\Bbb R_{>0}$. Don't you agree?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I would say that they are equal to some polynomial in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, or as others said I would call them "polynomial functions" rather than polynomials. In this case everything depends on definition of a polynomial. If a polynomial has strict definition of how it is expressed, they are obviously not polynomials.

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand, there's a subtle distinction on the definition of equality as functions (maybe we don't even define a polynomial as a function, but as a finite $k$-tuple of coefficients!). We could even say they something funny like that they belong to the same equivalence class of expression under the "defining the same function" relation.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Yes, the primal definition of a polynomial is quite abstract, and, at first, has, strictly speaking, nothing to do with a function. And, the definition of a function is not complete without adding domain and range.

Answer (score 0):

Well... yes, and no.

The point is: when we say a *polynomial*, we want so much to entail the fact that it is a finite linear combination of natural powers that it is usual, for example, to *define* it as a function $f:  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ (where $A$ is whatever ring we are on) which is zero for all, except finitely many $a \in A$. (c.f. Lang's Algebra). This is to entail the fact that there exists an "indeterminate", and coefficients. The coefficients are given by $f(n)$ ($f(0)$ is the first coefficient, of what would be $X^0$, $f(1)$ of $X^1$ etc).

If we were going to be nitpicky, even $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ is not a polynomial. This is what I think @Arthur is trying to entail in his comment. This is what he calls a polynomial function.

However, we of course have no shame on calling this function a polynomial, since there is an obvious equivalence. However, the expressions you mention are not capturing the essence of a polynomial in their form. Personally, I would not refer to them as polynomials, but instead simply as functions. But this is the same thing as refraining from calling a force (on the context of physics) a point on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and instead referring to it as a vector.

In the end of the day, it is all a matter of definitions and communicating oneself.

Comment: The distinction between a polynomial and a polynomial function is important when working with a finite field.  For any integer $x$, $x^2 \equiv x \mod 2$, which says that  the **functions** $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto x$ on the field $\mathbb Z_2$ (the integers mod 2) are the same,   However, the **polynomials** $X^2$ and $X$ over $\mathbb Z_2$ are different.  On an infinite field, two polynomials that agree as functions must be the same polynomial, so the distinction is not so important there.